# Control Firefox addons internet connections

Tags: firefox, security, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

Since there are many very interesting addons for Firefox I'd really like to use, I would love to be able to see which connections are attempted from the plugins installed on my Firefox. 
Even better would be being able to arbitrarily block single addons from attempting any internet connections at all.
Thanks for any help.